# RewriteEngine htaccess. Простенький вопрос

Tags: .htaccess, php, mod_rewrite

Совсем простой вопрос.

Как http://base/?mod=list&sort=name заменить на http://base/list/name/ где name - любой набор буквенных символов.

Я сделал так:

RewriteRule ^list/(.*)(/?)+$ index.php?mod=list&sort=$1 [L]

Такая ссылка работает: http://base/list/name, но когда в конце добавляю слэш, то не работает (http://base/list/name/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]*)(/?)+$ index.php?mod=list&sort=$1 [L]
```

Если в конце слеш, то в вашем варианте переменная $_GET['sort'] будет содержать "name/". Тут же мы его исключаем ([^/]*).

Answer (score 0):

У Вас какие-то странные квантификаторы.

```
(/?)+
```

Это означает слэш минимум один раз или ничего минимум один раз. Видимо проблема в интерпретации движком регекса этого не совсем корректного выражения.
По смыслу надо использовать

```
\/*
```

то есть слэш ноль или более раз.  В итоге имеем:

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.*?)\/*$ index.php?mod=list&sort=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?mod=$1&sort=$2 [L]
```